# How do you convert the colour scheme of an image loaded in p5.js from RGB( which I think is the default) to any other, like HSL?

Tags: javascript, colors, p5.js

I have tried adding this line //colorMode(HSL, 255); but this changes the original colours in the image. I want to keep the same colours in RGB, but adjust their HSL values through sliders.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit hard to understand but what i understand is this;

You loaded a image and want to change the colors on a HSL base, not RGB.

Did you load the pixel array from the image and are you changing those values? They are indeed RGB values. (strictly RGBA). My approach here would be to loop over all the pixels and extract their hue value ( https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/hue ) and then change it and apply that value to the pixel array.

I've made an example on how to convert rgb to hsl values without changing the colorMode here: https://editor.p5js.org/EthanHermsey/sketches/YozzL8y18

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  noStroke();

  //fill left half of canvas with RGB color
  let c = color(0, 126, 255);
  fill(c);
  rect(0, 0, width/2, height);

  //extract Hue, Saturation and Lightness
  let hueValue = floor( hue(c) );
  let saturationValue = saturation(c);
  let lightnessValue = lightness(c);  

  //Change hueValue? For example: add a random amount to it [-10 to 10]. 
  //The constraint helps to keep the value between 0 and 255;    
  //uncomment this next line;
  //hueValue = constrain( hueValue + floor(random(-10, 10)), 0, 255);

  //log new color
  console.log( `hsl(${ hueValue }, ${ saturationValue }%, ${ lightnessValue }%)` );

  //fill the right halve of the canvas with the new HSL color
  fill( `hsl(${ hueValue }, ${ saturationValue }%, ${ lightnessValue }%)` );
  rect(width/2, 0, width/2, height);
}
```